# Alignment in the split environment

Tags: math-mode, texpad

[image: My code and the result]
I'm learning to use Texpad on my iPad starting from two hours ago. I'd like the leading + symbols to be aligned with each other. The app doesn't allow me to use `&` for additional alignment tab, so I had to use `\cr` instead. But the initial tab has to be `&`, and the 'alignment' seems to be dysfunctional because I had to put my `&` where you can see it is because that's where the result gets as close it gets to my intention.

How can I have my split lines precisely aligned at the tab without messing around with the initial one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to be sure I understand what the problem is: Are you saying that the Texpad editor won't allow you to enter the character `&`? And, are you saying that you enter double-backslashes directly but that you can enter `\cr`?

Comment: Are you forced to use `equation*`?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. My tutorial book says I can put & before each line segment to be aligned, but when I ddo that the app says "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr".

Comment: @TeXnician No, just no other environment that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using `align*`. You could replace that with your combination of `equation*` and `split`. But don't forget to insert the line break.

[image: align]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (x+y)^8 = x^8 &+ 8x^7y + 28x^6y^2 + 56x^5y^3 + 70x^4y^4\\
  &+ 56x^3y^5 + 28x^2y^6 + 8xy^7 + y^8
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. So `align*` will be my environment of choice in this type of setting. Can you also recommend a source for learning to type math with LaTeX?

Comment: @HyobinLee For the easy things: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

alternatively with `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{multlined}[0.6\linewidth]
(x+y)^8 = x^8 + 8x^7y + 28x^6y^2 + 56x^5y^3 + 70x^4y^4\\
   + 56x^3y^5 + 28x^2y^6 + 8xy^7 + y^8
\end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `multilined` a math specific formatting? What do the `\[`, `\]` do?

Comment: @HyobinLee Yes, and `\[` and `\]` open or close math mode (display math).

Comment: So that must be an alternative to `$$`. Tons of stuff to learn.

Comment: @HyobinLee First thing to learn is that `$$` should be never used in LaTeX